# Program that uses singly-linked list is segfaulting when finding substring of a char* in C

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm writing a simple Lisp interpreter and I'm at the process of writing a S-exp parser. I've decided I'm going to incrementally parse the S-expressions, ie. by iterating over the
string S-expression and using character clues (like whether the charachter is a '(', ')', '"', ''', etc) to determine the type of the current token and its related value. I'm parsing the S-expression into memory using a singly linked list, that is, while iterating over the S-expression, my program would grab the token, parse it into a struct, and link it with the next token.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SNODE_LENGTH 256

enum styp {
    /*
    Enum that declares all possible types
    that a token could be in my lisp S-expression.
    In order, opening paranthesis, closing paranthesis,
    string, integer, decimal (float), charachter, nil
    */
    oparn,
    cparn,
    strn,
    intg,
    dec,
    chac,
    nil,
};


struct snode_t {
    /*
    When a S-expression is parsed every token is
    parsed into this. All data is stored in a
    string, but when operations need to be completed on it
    they are converted based on their type (defined by enum 
    styp typ).
    Each node points to the next one. When a S-exp is parsed,
    an snode_t is returned that is the first item. THe programmer
    can then iterate over the list and use the data stored in "val"
    to interpret code, etc.
    */
    char val[MAX_SNODE_LENGTH];
    enum styp typ;
    struct snode_t* nxt;
};

struct snode_t* node() {
    /*
    Function returns the pointer to a struct snode_t
    which has had memory allocated for it. This function
    is just for convenience.
    */
    struct snode_t* tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct snode_t*));
    tmp->nxt = malloc(sizeof(struct snode_t*));
    return tmp;
}

char* sstring(char* str, int s, int e) {
    /*
    Takes a string, a starting index and an 
    end index, and allocates the memory for a substring,
    creates a substring and returns it. Saves programmer
    time fiddling with memory when getting a substring.
    */
    size_t n = e - s + 2;
    // n is the number of bytes needed to be allocated
    char* sub = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
    memcpy(sub, &str[s], n-1);
    sub[n] = '\0';
    return sub;
}

struct snode_t* psexp(char* str) {
        struct snode_t* head = node();
        // head is the first item in the linked list.
        // head is the struct that is returned once 
        // the function completes.
        
        struct snode_t* aft = node();
        // aft contains the current struct.
        // once the type of a token is determined,
        // aft is set to the "nxt" value of the current
        // struct. aft is then assigned the according values.

        int p = 1;
        // indicates the position in the string. Starts 
        // at 1 because the first index of a properly formatted
        // S-exp will always be a closing bracket.
        // Note that this doesn't consider trailing whitespace,
        // I'm only writing functions that do the bare minimum
        // at this point so that I can make it more robust 
        // and safe later.

        if(str[0] == '(') {
            head->val[0] = '(';
            head->val[1] = '\0';
            head->typ = oparn;
            aft = head->nxt;
        }

        while(str[p] != '\0') {
            if(str[p] == '(') {
                head->val[0] = '(';
                head->val[1] = '\0';
                aft->typ = oparn;
            } else if(str[p] == ')') {
                head->val[0] = ')';
                head->val[1] = '\0';
                aft->typ = cparn;
            } else if(str[p] == '"') {
                // if the current charachter is a
                // ", all the following charachters
                // until the next " comprise a string
                // this next set of lines finds the 
                // position of the next " after the current one,
                // and uses that number to produce a substring
                // This substring is then stored in the current
                // struct.

                int s = p;
                int e;
                p++;
                
                while(str[p] != '"') {
                    p++;    
                }

                e = p++;
                
                char* tocp = sstring(str, s, e);
                strcpy(aft->val, tocp);
                aft->typ = strn;
            }

            aft->nxt = node();
            aft = aft->nxt;
            // the current struct is shifted to the next one.
        }
        return head;
}

int main() {
    psexp("(\"hello world!\")");
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this I get no warnings or errors, however, I get a segfault when running it. I've tested the node function and the sstring function, so I'm reasonably certain the memory faults lay in the psexp function.

I'm not sure what about the way I've allocated memory is wrong, before linking one struct to another I make sure I allocate the memory. What could be causing my segfault?

NOTE: At the moment psexp only concerns itself with brackets and strings, but as soon as I get strings to work (the area I presume to be causing the segfault) I intend to add the whole Enum's worth of data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `node`, you are doing `malloc` for the size of a *pointer* to the node rather than then full size of the `struct`.

After that fix, the program loops infinitely

Preallocating `nxt` is bad. `node` should only allocate a new node and *not* two.

Doing `malloc` in `sstring` leaks memory. Better to pass the target buffer as an argument.

For the `'('` and `')'` cases, `p` was never incremented, so if we hit one, we would loop forever

The linked list code needs a rework.

Here's a refactored version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SNODE_LENGTH 256

enum styp {
    /*
       Enum that declares all possible types that a token could be in my
        lisp S-expression. In order, opening paranthesis, closing paranthesis,
        string, integer, decimal (float), charachter, nil */
    oparn,
    cparn,
    strn,
    intg,
    dec,
    chac,
    nil,
};

struct snode_t {
    /*
       When a S-expression is parsed every token is parsed into this. All
        data is stored in a string, but when operations need to be completed
        on it they are converted based on their type (defined by enum styp
        typ). Each node points to the next one. When a S-exp is parsed, an
        snode_t is returned that is the first item. THe programmer can then
        iterate over the list and use the data stored in "val" to interpret
        code, etc. */
    char val[MAX_SNODE_LENGTH];
    enum styp typ;
    struct snode_t *nxt;
};

struct snode_t *
node()
{
    /*
       Function returns the pointer to a struct snode_t which has had memory
        allocated for it. This function is just for convenience. */
#if 0
    struct snode_t *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct snode_t *));
    tmp->nxt = malloc(sizeof(struct snode_t *));
#endif

#if 0
    struct snode_t *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct snode_t));
    tmp->nxt = malloc(sizeof(struct snode_t));
#endif

#if 1
    struct snode_t *tmp = calloc(1,sizeof(*tmp));
#endif

    return tmp;
}

char *
sstring(char *str, int s, int e, char *sub)
{
    /*
       Takes a string, a starting index and an end index, and allocates the
        memory for a substring, creates a substring and returns it. Saves
        programmer time fiddling with memory when getting a substring. */
    size_t n = e - s + 2;

    // n is the number of bytes needed to be allocated
#if 0
    char *sub = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
#endif

    memcpy(sub, &str[s], n - 1);
    sub[n] = 0;
    return sub;
}

// append -- allocate a new node and append to tail of list
struct snode_t *
append(struct snode_t **head)
{
    struct snode_t *cur;
    struct snode_t *prev;

    // find the tail of the list
    prev = NULL;
    for (cur = *head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->nxt)
        prev = cur;

    cur = node();

    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->nxt = cur;
    else
        *head = cur;

    return cur;
}

struct snode_t *
psexp(char *str)
{
    struct snode_t *head = NULL;

    // head is the first item in the linked list.
    // head is the struct that is returned once
    // the function completes.

    struct snode_t *aft = NULL;

    // aft contains the current struct.
    // once the type of a token is determined,
    // aft is set to the "nxt" value of the current
    // struct. aft is then assigned the according values.

    int p = 1;

    int s;
    int e;

    // indicates the position in the string. Starts
    // at 1 because the first index of a properly formatted
    // S-exp will always be a closing bracket.
    // Note that this doesn't consider trailing whitespace,
    // I'm only writing functions that do the bare minimum
    // at this point so that I can make it more robust
    // and safe later.

    while (str[p] != 0) {
        aft = append(&head);

        switch (str[p]) {
        case '(':
            aft->val[0] = '(';
            aft->val[1] = 0;
            aft->typ = oparn;
            p++;
            break;

        case ')':
            aft->val[0] = ')';
            aft->val[1] = 0;
            aft->typ = cparn;
            p++;
            break;

        case '"':
            // if the current charachter is a
            // ", all the following charachters
            // until the next " comprise a string
            // this next set of lines finds the
            // position of the next " after the current one,
            // and uses that number to produce a substring
            // This substring is then stored in the current
            // struct.

            s = p;

            p++;
            while (str[p] != '"') {
                p++;
            }

            e = p++;

            sstring(str, s, e, aft->val);
            aft->typ = strn;
        }

#if 0
        aft->nxt = node();
        aft = aft->nxt;
#endif
        // the current struct is shifted to the next one.
    }

    return head;
}

int
main()
{
    psexp("(\"hello world!\")");
    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Just as a side note - what does the #if 0 within some of the functions actually do? I've only ever really seen preprocessor directives used to make code more robust or customisable, ie. to check whether a header is defined and if not define it, or for user customisation before compilation. – Bithov Vin

I use `#if 0` as a way to "comment out" code by getting the preprocessor (`cpp`) to include/elide code. It's cleaner than wrapping the code in `/*` and `*/` pairs. I also use `#if 1` to mark "experimental/new" code I write.

Here I use it [as a teaching tool] to show old/original code vs new/improved code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif
```

Or:

```
#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

For my own code, when I'm sure the code is correct, I'll remove the `#if 0` and keep the `#else` code [removing the `#if/else/endif` lines] to leave the clean/simple/correct code.

So, when you understand the differences, you can also remove the directives and leave only the correct code.

Note that I would have used the `#if 0` trick in `psexp` to show how to fix it, but the changes were so extensive that using the preprocessor directives would have made things *more* difficult to understand.

Comment: The amount of effort you put into this answer is phenomenal. I really appreciate the corrections and the time you took to help me :)

Comment: Just as a side note - what does the #if 0 within some of the functions actually do? I've only ever really seen preprocessor directives used to make code more robust or customisable, ie. to check whether a header is defined and if not define it, or for user customisation before compilation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one bug:

```
struct snode_t* tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct snode_t*));
                                                  ^
                                                ups... pointer
```

So you allocate memory for a "pointer to struct snode_t" when you really want a "struct snode_t".

Correct it to

```
struct snode_t* tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct snode_t));
```

or better

```
struct snode_t* tmp = malloc(sizeof *tmp);
```

Further, this is pretty strange:

```
tmp->nxt = malloc(sizeof(struct snode_t*));
```

what you normally do when creating a new node is:

```
tmp->nxt = NULL;
```

In a linked-list, you never `malloc` anything to the next-pointer.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers - I've fixed these issues with my code. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me :)

Comment: ...no pun intended.